# Why are all indexes in Rust of type usize?

Tags: indexing, rust

Rust's `std::ops::Index<T>` [only](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ops/trait.Index.html) supports `T` being a `usize`.  What is the reason behind this?

Also, there is no advice to "try using usize" when you attempt to use anything else, just a "trait `[&'static str]: core::ops::Index<u8>` not satisfied" error.  Is this maybe because they plan to support more types `T`, but delayed doing so for some reason?

Comment: There actually are hints - *"note: slice indices are of type `usize`"* on an array, and *"the type `std::vec::Vec<&str>` cannot be indexed by `u8`"* on a vector. Admittedly they're not as clear as they could be, though. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b5b9b067d15266c9a89df5d7f2c1fd84&version=stable&backtrace=0

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Rust's `std::ops::Index<T>` only supports `T` being a `usize`.

This is just not true.  [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html), for example, accepts any type that the key type can borrow to (so you can index a `HashMap<String, _>` using a `&str`).

*Slices* only allow you to index them using `usize`, as do all container types that either pretend to be, or actually *are*, linear in memory.  That's because `usize` is the *correct* type with which to index them.  Any other type would either not be able to access the full potential range of the container, or would allow for indices that cannot possibly exist.

People have asked in the past about adding smaller types to slice indexing, but this would be backward-incompatible, so it's not going to happen any time soon.

Comment: How would adding indexing with smaller types be backwards incompatible?

Comment: @delnan Currently, `some_arr[0]` works because there is only *one* implementation of `Index` for slices.  If you added others, the compiler could no longer decide which one you wanted.  At least, that's how I remember it.

Comment: Oh, good point. There is one way out (aside from smarter inference): [allow `i32` indices](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=27e3abd1249a3d0b3f66c8a54a0b0cfe&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: I see.  It's the backwards compatibility issue that breaks adding more types.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually I wonder if Rust's preference for `i32` might make `some_arr[0]` still work, but as `i32` rather than `usize`.

Comment: I am new to Rust and trying to get my head around it.  I do not understand the backward-compatibility issue you're mentioning.  I'm imagining that at some point the only value allowed was usize.  But Rust differentiates **slices** from a **single index**.  Wouldn't a u32 or similar integer always be safe for indexing?  Thanks!

Comment: @MikeWilliamson: First, you're forgetting that Rust has type inference.  If you could suddenly *also* index by `u32`, then cases where Rust inferred the type of a variable based on its usage as an index would no longer compile due to there being multiple possible solutions.  Secondly, you're forgetting that Rust also targets embedded processors which might only have 16-bit `usize`s, meaning a `u32` is *not* always safe for indexing.  Third: when I said "slice", I mean `[T]`, not `a..b` which is a `Range`.

Comment: Thanks, @DK.  Actually, I wasn't "forgetting"... I just didn't know yet!  ;-p   The second issue - allowing for embedded & tiny processors (or perhaps really huge ones some day) - makes a lot of sense. I was just assuming that "u32 would always be big enough, but not so big that it wasted space".  My ignorance there.

Comment: There’s an actual use case for using types other than `usize` on linear containers: tagged integers. Suppose you’re working with some geometric properties and you have arrays with indexed by vertex IDs and other arrays with (say) face or edge IDs. It could be very easy to mismatch those IDs if they are plain `usize`s, giving origin to hard to track bugs (own experience).

Comment: This answer just states "usize is the correct type with which to index them" but doesn't say why.