# Do I have to use a usize to access elements of a vector?

Tags: rust

I have a 2D vector that rejects indexing using `i32` values, but works if I cast those values using `as usize`:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Color;

struct Pixel {
    color: Color,
}

fn shooting_star(p: &mut Vec<Vec<Pixel>>, x: i32, y: i32, w: i32, h: i32, c: Color) {
    for i in x..=w {
        for j in y..=h {
            p[i][j].color = c.clone();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

When I compile, I get the error message

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `i32: std::slice::SliceIndex<[std::vec::Vec<Pixel>]>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:11:13
   |
11 |             p[i][j].color = c.clone();
   |             ^^^^ slice indices are of type `usize` or ranges of `usize`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::slice::SliceIndex<[std::vec::Vec<Pixel>]>` is not implemented for `i32`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::Index<i32>` for `std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<Pixel>>`
```

If I change the code to have

```
p[i as usize][j as usize].color = c.clone();
```

Then everything works fine. However, this feels like it would be a really bizarre choice with no reason not to be handled by the `Vec` type.

In the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html), there are plenty of examples like

```
assert_eq!(vec[0], 1);
```

By my understanding, if a plain number with no decimal is by default an `i32`, then there's no reason using an `i32` to index shouldn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike Java, C# or even C++, numeric literals in Rust do not have a fixed type. The numeric type of a literal is usually inferred by the compiler, or explicitly stated using a suffix (`0usize`, `0.0f64`, and so on). In that regard, the type of the `0` literal in `assert_eq!(vec[0], 1);` is *inferred* to be a `usize`, since Rust allows `Vec` indexing by numbers of type `usize` only.

As for the rationale behind using `usize` as the indexing type: a `usize` is equivalent to a *word* in the target architecture. Thus, a `usize` can refer to the index/address of all possible memory locations for the computer the program is running on. Thus, the maximum possible length of a vector is the maximum possible value that can be contained in a `isize` (`isize::MAX == usize::MAX / 2`). Using `usize` sizes and indices for a `Vec` prevents the creation and usage of a vector larger than the available memory itself.

Furthermore, the usage of an unsigned integer just large enough to refer all possible memory locations allows the removal of two dynamic checks, one, the supplied size/index is non-negative (if `isize` was used, this check would have to be implemented manually), and two, creating a vector or dereferencing a value of a vector will not cause the computer to run out of memory. However, the latter is guaranteed only when the type stored in the vector fits into one word.

Comment: that makes sense, though its kinda a pain. How much of a performance impact would it really have to be implicitly cast? If something is that speed critical, then shouldn't they be using a different data structure anyway?

Comment: "Unlike Java, C# or even C++, numeric literals in Rust do not have a fixed type." [???](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) "Thus, the maximum possible length of a vector is the maximum possible value that can be contained in a usize." => ["The theoretical upper bound on object and array size is the maximum isize value.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types.html#machine-dependent-integer-types)

Comment: If you mean to ask why implementations of `SliceIndex` (the trait that allows a type to be used for indexing) aren't made for other numeric types, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40260098/4038191) puts it nicely.

Comment: @Stargateur: C++: `auto x = 0; // x: int` Rust: `let x = 0; // x: {integer} (to be inferred later)`. Thanks for the max object/array size tip! I have edited my answer.