# Is disallowing accessing the elements of an array with a different type than usize a design choice?

Tags: c++, arrays, c, types, rust

I am trying to access an element of an array. I am sure that the type that I am trying to use is enough to index the whole array and a 64-bit index is overkill.

I have minor experience in C and C++ and I know that it's possible there.

I am unsure about several points and want to ask:

- Is it a design choice?
- Are C and C++ converting the type to `usize` when trying to access an element of an array?
- Can I convince / force Rust to use another type to access an array element?
- Is accessing an element with a smaller type faster? (e.g. is the *speed of* `usize` < `u8`?)

#### Not working Rust code

```rust
fn main() {
    let some_array = [10; 255];
    let some_index: u8 = 255;

    println!("{}", some_array[some_index])
}
```

#### Working C code

```c
int main() {
    char array[255] = {0};
    char index = 12;

    printf("Element: %d", array[index]);
}
```

Comment: Access with a `u8` is often going to be slower, because you often have to add a conversion step from `u8` to 32 bits or 64 bits. This is why C++ has the `uint_fast8_t` type, which is usually a 32-bit type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it a design choice?

Yes, for reasons described below.

> Are C and C++ converting the type to `usize` when trying to access an element of an array?

Yes. Indexing into an array is defined as arithmetic on a pointer, and pointers are `usize`-sized by definition (32 bits on 32-bit systems, etc.)

> Can I convince / force Rust to use another type to access an array element?

No. Well, kind of, but not for arbitrary types. You can implement [`SliceIndex<[T]>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.SliceIndex.html) for a type you control to be able to use it to index into a slice. But this will still be implemented by converting to `usize` internally.

> Is accessing an element with a smaller type faster? (e.g. is the *speed of* `usize` < `u8`?)

No, since pointers are always the same size, there's no speed advantage to using smaller types *for indexing*. In fact, it may well be *slower* to use a smaller type, if zero-extending the value forces the compiler to use a slower instruction. But this is not the most important thing to consider when choosing types for your program.

It *can* save memory to use a smaller type if you are storing indices in a long-lived data structure, as opposed to just using them for indexing. When that's the case, it might be a good idea to implement the conversion from/to `usize` when storing/retrieving from the data structure.

### See also

- [Why are all indexes in Rust of type usize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259802/why-are-all-indexes-in-rust-of-type-usize)

Answer (score 3):

Indexing into an array or vector is always done using `usize` in Rust. This is the conventional type for any value representing a length or size. If you have an index of some other type, you can cast it:

```rust
fn main() {
    let some_array = [10; 255];
    let some_index: u8 = 255;

    println!("{}", some_array[some_index as usize])
}
```

`usize` is the same as `u32` on a 32 bit system and `u64` on a 64 bit system. There is almost never going to be a performance difference of using these over a smaller type. The cast has effectively zero overhead; it's just treating the same raw binary data as if it were a different type.

It is possible to index over custom data structures with other types, by implementing the [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) trait for them.

Comment: When I am typecasting in rust, I am physically changing the type or just cheating the type system?

Comment: @DamianGrzanka it's more like cheating the type system - there's no overhead.

Comment: Ok, but you should remember that you can fit 58 u8 in uszie (when 64-bit) maybe in main memory isn't a deal but in the cache is it (according to my math). t

Comment: @DamianGrzanka 58 * 8-bit = 464bits. A 64 bit number is smaller than a 464 bit number.

Comment: @Shepmaster I think it's clear that's a typo - it's supposed to be 8 not 58.