# Why can't I use types other than `usize` to index an element in a Vector?

Tags: rust

I was trying out Vector's in Rust where I encountered issues with the compiler complaining of using types other than `usize` to index elements in a Vector. I referred various sources including the one in [this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259802/why-are-all-indexes-in-rust-of-type-usize) but couldn't understand the exact reason.

One reason being pointed out is that the `len` property of a vector Struct is of type `usize` and hence we are using `usize` to index the Vector. I know that `usize` is 32 bit in a 32-bit machine and 64 bits in a 64-bit machine. But, why can't we use say `u32` here to index the collection?

I am also aware that the Rust STD has not implemented the `Index` or `IndexMut` trait for `u32` but why?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.